# What's the difference between p4 duplicate and branching and merging?

Tags: perforce

So in perforce, we have `p4 integrate` `p4 duplicate` `p4 copy` and `p4 branch` what's the difference and when should I use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help branch

    branch -- Create, modify, or delete a branch view specification
    ...
```

You can use this command to (optionally) create a branch spec for later use with `copy`, `integrate`, `merge`, and/or `populate`.  Note that all of those commands can also take an on-the-fly mapping in the form of two file paths, and if you're using streams you don't use branch specs because the mapping is generated automatically based on the parent and child stream.

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help copy

    copy -- Copy one set of files to another
    ...
```

Opens the target files in such a way as to create new head revisions that are identical to those of the source files.  (This may in some cases overwrite changes in the target -- if you're using streams, there are guards on copy to help prevent this, but otherwise you should always use `integrate` unless you're absolutely certain that you want to overwrite the target.)

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help integrate

    integrate -- Integrate one set of files into another
    ...
```

Opens the target files (and schedules resolves) in such a way as to create new head revisions that combine all outstanding changes from the source with existing changes in the target.  Actually performing the merges is done via the `resolve` command prior to `submit`.

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help duplicate

    duplicate -- duplicate revisions with integration history (unsupported)
    ...
```

Like it says, unsupported.  This has specific use cases that you will hopefully never need to discover.